# Tkinter opens Toplevel even though it was never asked to

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this program where I have one tkinter main root in one module that is supposed to be able to open this other tkinter Toplevel window from another module. However, once I run the original main root module the Toplevel root is being run instead of the main root even if I dont even have a top.mainloop(). When I close the Toplevel window the mainroot runs.

My code looks something like this:

main.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import top

root = Tk()

def openTop():
    top.top()


def getRoot():
    global root
    return root

def main():
   
    
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

top.py

```
from tkinter import *
import main

subRoot = Toplevel(main.getRoot())


# a lot of functions etc
```

I never even have a subRoot.mainloop() anywhere. To me this seems very strange.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `mainloop` per thread.  That mainloop processes messages for all windows created in that thread.

By the way, you have created a dangerous circular import there.  It looks like you have a `top` function within `top`.  You should pass the root window to that function, and create the subwindow there, not at the global level.

Comment: Hmm, okay I thought about that but I have quite a lot of global constants dependant on subRoot in top. But if that is the only way...